# How to map an indexed array data source in DataTables

Tags: javascript, json, datatables

Say i have an array as the data source for DataTables, delivered through AJAX

```
{
  "data": [
    [
      "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask",
      "Tiger Nixon",
      "System Architect",
      "Edinburgh",
      "5421",
      "2011/04/25",
      "$320,800"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I want to ignore the first cell and not output it as a column, so how can i map the indexed data to the columns? I have already tried this, but it gives an error:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "data/objects.txt",
        "columns": [
            { "data": [1] },
            { "data": [2] },
            { "data": [3] },
            { "data": [4] },
            { "data": [5] },
            { "data": [6] }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined`

I also tried to reference the indexes like this

```
"data": 1
```

Doesn't work either.

If the source was an Object with keys, referencing would work like this:

```
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "extn" },
            { "data": "start_date" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ]
```

Comment: You can bind the first column and hide it later.

Comment: That would be a workaround, but mapping per index would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution myself, this code will make the first cell invisible and display the other cells:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "data/objects.txt",
        "columnDefs": [
            { "targets": [0], "visible": false },
            { "targets": '_all', "visible": true }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = {}
var keys = ['name', 'job', 'location', 'number', 'date', 'salary']
var arr = [
  'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask',
  'Tiger Nixon',
  'System Architect',
  'Edinburgh',
  '5421',
  '2011/04/25',
  '$120000'
]
.filter((item, i) => !!i)
.forEach((v, i) => obj[keys[i]] = v)

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: This could work as a workaround if there is no way to map indexes directly. I don't want to manipulate the source data array because the set is very large, 100 000 rows. Every manipulation is very expensive, performance-wise.